# TypeError: argument must be string or read-only buffer, not bytearray

Tags: python, pycrypto

I'm building a decryptor using DES ECB

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES

code = 'cb9108614c943d96bedd2bae934c5aa3d5c4318f81cc81f255127292f2935bbc0a8990f36c1ffa20a0639ed8a6989bacc36bd11f6b2ecdab'
key = b'5199D19B'
code= bytearray.fromhex(code)

print(code)

ciphert = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)
code = ciphert.decrypt(code)
code = code.decode('ISO-8859-1')

print(code)
```

but I keep getting this error

> File "test.py", line 17, in
>
> code = ciphert.decrypt(code)
>
> File "build/bdist.macosx-10.14-intel/egg/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py", line 295, in decrypt
>
> TypeError: argument must be string or read-only buffer, not bytearray

Ive been working on this for hours now and can't figure out another way to store the variable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import DES
>>> code = 'cb9108614c943d96bedd2bae934c5aa3d5c4318f81cc81f255127292f2935bbc0a8990f36c1ffa20a0639ed8a6989bacc36bd11f6b2ecdab'
>>> key = b'5199D19B'
>>> ciphert = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)
>>> ciphert.decrypt(code.decode('hex'))
'Well done, you have been able to decode the message. \x00\x00\x00'
```

Generally when passing ciphertext to a "decode" function in crypto libraries it should be passed as a `bytes` object (as ciphertext can contain arbitrary bytes in general).  For whatever reason it just doesn't accept a `bytearray` object--that would have to be implemented separately.

`code.decode('hex')` does the same thing you wanted--it converts a string of hex digits to their actual byte values.

#### Update for Python 3:

On Python 3 `code.decode('hex')` won't work.  Instead use `bytes.fromhex(code)` (similarly to `bytearray.fromhex` but just return an immutable `bytes` instance).

Comment: @user1438644 Nope that doesn't work.  On Python 3 when converting a str to bytes you have to supply an encoding.  OP is trying to convert a string of hex digits to their byte values.

Comment: Apparently it was just the version of python I was using. It works in 3 but not 2.7